# Hadoop Hive Group by with category

Tags: hadoop, hive

Folks,

We have one requirement for Hadoop Hive.

Basically we have data in following format.

customer name,product name, price

```
Test,prod1,10
Test,prod2,30
Test,prod3,20


Test1,prod1,20
Test1,prod2,30
Test1,prod2,30


 Test2,prod1,50
 Test2,prod2,40
 Test2,prod2,10
```

We need to find top 2 customers from above [ conditon ( The price of their product sum falls in to top 2 ]

e.g in the above example we need records for Test1 sum(price) = 20+30+30 = 80
                                             Test2 sum(price) = 50+40+10 = 100

Test customer does not qualify as sum of the price is 60.

basically customer and their product list for top 2 customers (if sum(price) is more they qualify)

Expected output. (records for Test customer should not come)

```
 Test1,prod1,20
 Test1,prod2,30
 Test1,prod2,30


 Test2,prod1,50
 Test2,prod2,40
 Test2,prod2,10
```

How to write HIVE query for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what hive version you have, but I will assume we can not use `IN()`

You will need to create a temporary table that holds the matched customers.

```
CREATE TABLE tempp 
    AS SELECT customer, sum(price) as v 
          FROM mytable group by customer ORDER BY v DESC LIMIT 2;
```

This temporary table will have these rows:

```
Test2   100.0
Test1   80.0
```

Then do a LEFT SEMI JOIN to get the matched

```
SELECT a.* FROM mytable a LEFT SEMI JOIN tempp t ON (a.customer = t.customer)
```

The output based on your table:

```
Test1   prod1   20
Test1   prod2   30
Test1   prod2   30
Test2   prod1   50
Test2   prod2   40
Test2   prod2   10
```

Comment: Hi is there any way to do it in a single Query without creating temp table. Because if data is updated frequently we may have to create temp table every time which is not ideal. I am using Hive 0.11

Comment: Try to look into hive subqueries, and do the temporary table creation in the second query.